How to speed up, decode h264 frames represented as array with gstreamer in qt application, all in code
I wrote a simple Qt class, which provide realtime decoding h264 frames, presented by qbytearray, into frames of I420 format, with preprocessing it to RGB. And display with paint event on simple widget. What is the main problem, I want to decrease delay in frame preprocessing (right now around 1,5 sec, on ubuntu 22.04 laptop with i7-intel), so it could show video faster. I'm newbie for gstreamer, just don't know how make it faster with additional gstreamer api.
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
#include <QImage>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/video/video.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsink.h>

class H264FrameProcessor : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    H264FrameProcessor(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~H264FrameProcessor();

public slots:
    void processFrame(const QByteArray &frame, int width, int height, int isIFrame);

signals:
    void frameProcessed(const QImage &image);

private:
    GstElement *pipeline;
    GstElement *appsrc;
    GstElement *h264parse;
    GstElement *decoder;
    GstElement *conv;
    GstElement *sink;
    GstBus *bus;
    GstMessage *msg;
    GstStateChangeReturn ret;
    bool initialized;

    void initializeGStreamer();
    void cleanupGStreamer();

    static GstFlowReturn onNewSample(GstAppSink *sink, gpointer user_data);
};

Implementation
#include "H264FrameProcessor.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/video/video.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsink.h>
#include <libyuv.h>

static QImage i420ToRgb32(const uint8_t *yuvData, int width, int height) {
    // Calculate the sizes of the Y, U, and V planes
    int ySize = width * height;
    int uvSize = (width * height) / 4;

    // Extract the Y, U, and V planes from the I420 data
    const uint8_t *yPlane = yuvData;
    const uint8_t *uPlane = yuvData + ySize;
    const uint8_t *vPlane = yuvData + ySize + uvSize;

    // Allocate memory for the RGB32 data
    uint8_t *rgb32Data = new uint8_t[width * height * 4];

    // Convert I420 to ARGB using libyuv
    libyuv::I420ToARGB(yPlane, width,
                       uPlane, width / 2,
                       vPlane, width / 2,
                       rgb32Data, width * 4,
                       width, height);

    // Create a QImage from the RGB32 data
    QImage rgbImage(rgb32Data, width, height, QImage::Format_RGB32);

    // Make a deep copy of the QImage to ensure the data is not deleted
    QImage image = rgbImage.copy();

    // Free the allocated memory for the RGB32 data
    delete[] rgb32Data;

    return image;
}

H264FrameProcessor::H264FrameProcessor(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent), initialized(false) {
    initializeGStreamer();
}

H264FrameProcessor::~H264FrameProcessor() {
    cleanupGStreamer();
}

void H264FrameProcessor::initializeGStreamer() {
    gst_init(nullptr, nullptr);

    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("video-pipeline");
    appsrc = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "source");
    h264parse = gst_element_factory_make("h264parse", "h264-parser");
    decoder = gst_element_factory_make("avdec_h264", "decoder");
    conv = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "converter");
    sink = gst_element_factory_make("appsink", "sink");

    if (!pipeline || !appsrc || !h264parse || !decoder || !conv || !sink) {
        qWarning() << "Not all elements could be created.";
        return;
    }

    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), appsrc, h264parse, decoder, conv, sink, nullptr);
    if (!gst_element_link_many(appsrc, h264parse, decoder, conv, sink, nullptr)) {
        qWarning() << "Elements could not be linked.";
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        return;
    }

    GstCaps *caps = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-h264", "stream-format", G_TYPE_STRING, "byte-stream", "alignment", G_TYPE_STRING, "nal", nullptr);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(appsrc), "caps", caps, nullptr);
    gst_caps_unref(caps);

    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(sink), "emit-signals", TRUE, "sync", FALSE, nullptr);
    g_signal_connect(sink, "new-sample", G_CALLBACK(onNewSample), this);

    ret = gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
        qWarning() << "Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.";
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        return;
    }

    initialized = true;
}

void H264FrameProcessor::cleanupGStreamer() {
    if (initialized) {
        gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
    }
}

void H264FrameProcessor::processFrame(const QByteArray &frame, int width, int height, int frameRate) {
    if (!initialized) {
        qWarning() << "GStreamer not initialized.";
        return;
    }

    // Set the caps on the appsrc element to specify the width and height
    GstCaps *caps = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-h264",
                                        "width", G_TYPE_INT, width,
                                        "height", G_TYPE_INT, height,
                                        "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, frameRate, 1,
                                        "stream-format", G_TYPE_STRING, "byte-stream",
                                        //"alignment", G_TYPE_STRING, "nal", // crash everything
                                        nullptr);

    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(appsrc), "caps", caps, nullptr);
    gst_caps_unref(caps);
#if 0
    // Push a new-segment event
    GstSegment segment = {
        GST_SEGMENT_FLAG_NONE,  // flags
        1.0,                    // rate
        1.0,                    // applied_rate
        GST_FORMAT_TIME,        // format
        0,                      // base
        0,                      // offset
        0,                      // start
        GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,    // stop
        0,                      // time
        0,                      // position
        GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE     // duration
    };
    GstEvent *event = gst_event_new_segment(&segment);
    gst_pad_push_event(gst_element_get_static_pad(appsrc, "src"), event);
#endif
    // Create a buffer from the frame data
    GstBuffer *buffer = gst_buffer_new_and_alloc(frame.size());
    GstMapInfo map;
    gst_buffer_map(buffer, &map, GST_MAP_WRITE);
    memcpy(map.data, frame.constData(), frame.size());
    gst_buffer_unmap(buffer, &map);

    // Push the buffer into the pipeline
    GstFlowReturn ret;
    g_signal_emit_by_name(appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);
    gst_buffer_unref(buffer);

    if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK) {
        qWarning() << "Error pushing buffer to GStreamer pipeline.";
    }

    // Check the pipeline state
 /* It have a side effect like stopping all in this function*/
#if 0
    GstState state;
    gst_element_get_state(pipeline, &state, nullptr, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE);
    qDebug() << "Pipeline state:" << state;
#endif
}

GstFlowReturn H264FrameProcessor::onNewSample(GstAppSink *sink, gpointer user_data) {
    GstSample *sample;
    GstBuffer *buffer;
    GstMapInfo map;
    QImage image;

    sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(sink);
    buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);
    gst_buffer_map(buffer, &map, GST_MAP_READ);

    GstCaps *caps = gst_sample_get_caps(sample);
    GstStructure *structure = gst_caps_get_structure(caps, 0);
    int width, height;
    gst_structure_get_int(structure, "width", &width);
    gst_structure_get_int(structure, "height", &height);

    // Ensure the image format is correct
    const gchar *format = gst_structure_get_string(structure, "format");
    if (format && strcmp(format, "I420") == 0) {
        image = i420ToRgb32(map.data, width, height);
    } else {
        qWarning() << "Unsupported pixel format:" << format;
    }

    H264FrameProcessor *processor = static_cast<H264FrameProcessor *>(user_data);
    emit processor->frameProcessed(image);

    gst_buffer_unmap(buffer, &map);
    gst_sample_unref(sample);

    return GST_FLOW_OK;
}


1.5s is yet very good. You shouldn't hope much better. Without hardware acceleration it'd take ~10 times more time. You may try another plugin such as vaapih264dec, vah264dec, openh264dec, nvh264dec

Thank you Mike! I will try it. But for me it's an interesting detail, If I want ot create several instances of my class, for different cameras, which problems could cause.  Just I have a sample with ffpmeg, it works brilliant. No delay, no artifacts.

Please clarify exactly what you mean by "delay in frame preprocessing".  Even on a basic laptop it should be possible to decode an h264 stream in real time (encoding is another matter).

@G.M. It depends. Even ignoring the resolution (which obviously does affect the processing speed), converting the color space and making a copy of the image may be costly, also depending on the capacity of the decoder (which may trade quality with performance) or even considering the format in which every "channel" may be stored, and therefore the possible conversion to another color space.

Ok, I will change part of code for qImage. Never the less, may be there is a way to set convertion right to gstreamer? Decoded picture return in I420 format, So I change it to RGB with libyuv, classic linux approach.
